# share on LAN in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: lan

how to share file over LAN in ubuntu 12.10.
I have shared some files , but on the other machine it keep asking for password

Comment: Are both machines running Ubuntu or is the other machine running Windows or something else?

Comment: Do you want to set up a browsable shared directory, or do you want to share just one file, one time?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the share, check the "Guest access (for people without a user account)" option.

[image: Sharing Options]

If guest access is not checked, you will need to provide the user name and password of a user on the Ubuntu source machine who has access to that file.

Note: Please use a share name up to 11 characters long and preferably without spaces for universal compatibility.